# How to collect as much information before returning error

Tags: http, go

```
func About(c echo.Context) error {
        about := newInfo()
        memory, err := getMemory()
        if err != nil {
                log.Errorf("Failed to get memory %v", err)
                return err
        }
        about.SystemInfo["memory"] = memory

        version, err := getVersion()
        if err != nil {
                log.Errorf("Failed to get version details %v", err)
                return err
        }

        about.Version = version
        serialNo ,err= getSerialInfo()
        if err != nil{
                log.Errorf("Failed to get Product code %v", err)
                return err
        }
        about.SerialNo = serialNo
        network, err := localAddress()
        if err != nil {
                log.Errorf("Failed to get Network details %v", err)
                return err
        }
        about.Network = network

        return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, about)

}
```

This is one my http endpoint where when /about request comes I am redirecting to this function. I am trying to get some system related info. What I want to do is, I want to collect as much info as I want and return error in last. For example, if memory returns error, instead of returning error directly I want to  go ahead of the code and get all info. Stuck on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution for non-fatal errors (ie: errors where it is ok to continue), is to save the last non-nil error.

For example:

```
var lastErr err
mem, err := ....
if err != nil {
  // Overwrite lastErr only if an error was encountered.
  lastErr = err
}

version, err := ...
if err != nil {
  lastErr = err
}
```

At the end of the function, return `lastErr` as you please.

Other variants on the theme include:

- `firstErr` (don't overwrite if it is not `nil`)
- a slice of errors (append to it for every non-nil error)
- more structured: save the error alongside the data you are returning. ie: have a `about.Errors []error` field, or even one for each operation: `about.Errors map[string]error` and save each error: `about.Errors["memory"] = errFromMemoryLookup`

If you want to know about errors alongside the actual information, you should probably go with the last one.

Comment: can you explain 3rd one with an example

Comment: Added a brief example. Which you choose really depends on the amount of details you want/need.

Comment: Note that some third-party Go packages return an `error` interface value whose underlying concrete type is or contains `[]error`, which lets simple callers do the usual `ret, err := f(); if err != nil { ... }` thing, but also lets fancy callers do `ret, err := f(); if err != nil { if fancy, ok := err.(CompoundError); ok { ... handle compound error specially ... } ... }`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to return the error at once, just check all errors in last and return a custom error, or you can return last error as mentioned by @Marc

```
 func About(c echo.Context) error {
        about := newInfo()
        memory, errMemory := getMemory()
        if errMemory != nil {
                log.Errorf("Failed to get memory %v", errMemory)
        } else {
          about.SystemInfo["memory"] = memory
        }

        version, errVersion := getVersion()
        if errVersion != nil {
                log.Errorf("Failed to get version details %v", errVersion)
        } else {
          about.Version = version
        }

        serialNo ,errSerial= getSerialInfo()
        if errSerial != nil{
                log.Errorf("Failed to get Product code %v", errSerial)
        } else {
          about.SerialNo = serialNo
        }

        network, errNet := localAddress()
        if errNet != nil {
                log.Errorf("Failed to get Network details %v", errNet)
        } else {
          about.Network = network
        }

        if errNet != nil || errSerial != nil || errVersion != nil || errMemory != nil  {
          // return a custom error, here
        }
        return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, about)
}
```